# Why does my furnace need power resets all the time?

Tags: heating, furnace

I just installed a smart LUX thermostat and I know it's right but even with my old thermostat it was doing the same thing. My temp will be set at 70 yet its 62 in my house. I have to go to the basement and turn the power to the gas furnace off then on. It kicks on with in a few seconds and runs fine the later in the day I'll have to do it again. Wtf is going on with this thing? It just started doing this with in the last week  it is a heat and air unit that's gas and I know its wilted right because it will work fine once I power cycle it.

Comment: You need to specify the name and model of your furnace, any answers would be guessing.

Comment: Yes, what make and model is your furnace? Can you post its wiring diagram, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a safety circuit is telling your furnace not to turn on again until it is serviced. A dirty air filter can be the cause, your control board usually has LED’s that indicate what the fault is by a sequence of flashes. It is best to find the cause of the fault not just powercycling. The brand and model of the furnace and the sequence of flashes could tell us what the fault is. A dirty filter is a first thing to check as they are most often overlooked.